# Switch Django's version

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm using different Django framework version(1.3, 1.4, 1.5) for different projects.
On my laptop, I have to reinstall Django with pip, every time I want to switch to another project.
Is there an easier(less stupid! :D) way, that i can automatically switch to the version I need? Something like NVM for node?

Comment: Nope. Sorry. What you can do is create re-usable python virtual environments.

Comment: The consensus seems to be virtualenv :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion the easiest way is to use a `requirements.txt` file for `virtualenv`. With a `requirements.txt` file you can specify the version and every other person that uses your project can just use `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

This is the way how almost all big projects do it (the "pythonic" way).

Here you also have a small [introduction](http://www.mahdiyusuf.com/post/5282169518/beginners-guide-easy-install-pip-and-virtualenv-1).

Answer (score 1):

The standard method is to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/). With this you can make standalone python interpreters running there own set of libraries (django versions) and/or python versions. Switching between them is as easy as typing `virtualenv my_env_with_django_1.4`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use `virtualenv` to install each project in its own isolated environment, with its own installation of libraries.